# I am getting a new 500 unknown error timeout randomly

Tags: python, selenium, aws-device-farm

I've been using device farm for some CI tests, everything was working good and fine since I set up but in the last 2 weeks something changed. I keep getting randomly a 500 unknown error, apparently the website failed to load, which doesn't happen manually, it only happens randomly. I'm running 50 tests at a time and 2-10 tests will fail due to this reason and it's not always the same test it's random everytime.

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7f136854fdd0>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT\\n...\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777F74ED+237]\\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777F74BD+189]\\n"}}'}
```

I'm unsure what is causing this, we have whitelisted the IP's and it was working all fine some time ago.

Comment: I think it's not related to Selenium.

Comment: See [this thread on IP ranges for desktop testing](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=315292&tstart=0). The post was updated.

Comment: how are you running 50 tests at once?